# the latest version of geometry.sty

Tags: geometry

Good day to all,

I want this extension of the latest updates. however, from CTAN the file is in `.dtx` and I am not well versed to convert to `.sty`.

Anybody could advice? or I do appreciate if someone could share the `.sty` file here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! `geometry` is a part of any latex distribution. instead adding it manually rather use tools of your latex installation to load it or upgrade it. for example, miktex provide utility `console` by which you can easy do aforementioned.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to I would strongly urge you not to install packages from CTAN manually. Many TeX distributions have facilities to automatically install and update packages (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864) and these should be preferred. If you install packages manually you can risk version incompatibilities that are usually avoided when you let your TeX distribution manage things.

Answer (score 1):

According to `Readme.md`:

```
[manual installation]
  * To get geometry.sty out of geometry.dtx
        $ tex geometry.dtx 
    or  $ (la)tex geometry.ins (after first extraction)
  * To build documentation
        $ latex geometry.dtx  
    or  $ latex geometry.drv (after first extraction)
  * Put the derived files in the proper directories:
      -  tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
      -  doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf
      -  source/latex/geometry/geometry.dtx
```

So `tex geometry.dtx` should do the trick.